# After converting a mesh to a curve , how to have a smooth curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

i have converted a square mesh to a curve , so i have a really narrow agle i didnt find any way in the curve editor to modify that , and i cannot change the handle of this cuvre ..i just want to transform this thoses line into real curve but they stay straight ...

is there a way with a converted mesh; to modify the lines into a real curve ?  [image]

Answer (score 3):

In the left menu (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>) > *Tool* > *Set Spline Type* > *Bezier*